# GC overhead while streaming large files with JAX-RS

Tags: hibernate, jax-rs, inputstream, resteasy, mssql-jdbc

I need to stream large files with JAX-RS (WildFly 10, so RESTeasy and Hibernate) to/from SQL Server (notice that SQL Server JDBC driver supports streaming).

The goal is obviously to have the stream passthrough to/from the database, without exhausting memory.

This is the endpoint:

```
@Path("files")
public class FileEndpoint {

    @Inject
    FileRepository fileRepository;

    @POST
    public void post(InputStream stream) {
        fileRepository.save(stream);
    }

    @GET
    public InputStream get() {
        InputStream stream = fileRepository.getBlob().getBinaryStream();
        // stream is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.PLPInputStream
        return stream; 
    }

}
```

Posting a 2GB file seem to work, e.g.

```
$ curl -XPOST http://localhost:8080/files --data-binary @file.bin
```

does not exhaust memory, while this

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:8080/files > /tmp/file.bin
```

after few seconds throws a OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.

Profiling shows how GC peaks during the GET:

[image: profiling]

But why? I tried this:

1. returning a `FileInputStream`: it does not overhead
2. writing the stream to disk: it does not overhead

So it seems that both the stream from the database and the RESTeasy response behave correctly, but when combined the GC overheads.

Thank you for every hint and, possibly, a solution!